# getting html input value inside javascript class

Tags: javascript, html, class

i am new to javascript and im making a BMI calculator. im making a class in javascript to produce the calculations. currently users could input their height (in feet and inches) and weight. when i run a method within my class. it keeps saying this.feet = null instead of grabbing the value from the input. my javascript code is below. result() is in my html for the submit button.

```
function calculator(feet,inches,weight) { 
    this.feet = feet.value;
    this.inches = inches.value;
    this.weight = weight.value;

    this.validateInput = function() {
        var errors = [];

        if(isNaN(this.feet) || this.feet < 0) {
            errors.push("Feet");
        }
        else {
            return this.feet
        };

        if(isNaN(this.inches) || this.inches < 0 || this.inches > 11) {
            errors.push("Inches")
        }
        else {
            return this.inches;
        };  

        if(isNaN(this.weight) || this.weight < 0) {
            errors.push("Weight");
        }
        else {
            return this.weight
        }
    };

    this.inchesConverter = function() {
        this.feet = parseFloat(feet);
        this.inches = parseFloat(inches);
        return parseInt(this.feet*12+this.inches);
    };

    this.bmi = function() {
        var height = this.inchesConverter();
        var validater = this.validateInput();

        for(r = 0; r < errors.length; r++){
            if(errors.length > 0) {
                return errors[r] + " must be a valid positive number.";
            }
            else {
                parseFloat((validateWeight * 703) / (Math.pow(height, 2))).toFixed(1);
            }
        }
    };      
};


var getWeight = document.getElementById('txtWeight');
var getFeet = document.getElementById('txtHeightFeet');
var getInches = document.getElementById('txtHeightInches');

var test = new calculator(getFeet, getInches, getWeight);
function result() {
    document.getElementById("lblBMI").innerHTML(test.bmi());
}
```

Comment: Can you elaborate your question, JavaScript has no classes.

Comment: @Teemu—it will have, sort of, in [*ed 6*](https://people.mozilla.org/~jorendorff/es6-draft.html) (if it becomes the standard…). ;-)

Comment: To give some help for your problem, log `this` to the console within `validateInput` to see, what you're actually referring to.

Comment: @RobG That'll be just some syntactic sugar, or "traps", as TJ Crowder has called those new "class" features in ES6 ; ). Thanks for the link, I haven't seen that before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out what my issue was. The problem arose from my for loop. Working code is posted below!

```
function calculator(feet,inches,weight) { 
    this.feet = feet.value;
    this.inches = inches.value;
    this.weight = weight.value;

    this.validateInput = function() {
        var errors = [];

        if(isNaN(this.feet) || this.feet < 0 || this.feet == "") {
            errors.push("feet");
        };
        if(isNaN(this.inches) || this.inches < 0 || this.inches > 11) {
            errors.push("inches")
        };
        if(isNaN(this.weight) || this.weight < 0 || this.weight == "") {
            errors.push("weight");
        };

        return errors;
        console.log(errors);
    }; 

    this.inchesConverter = function() {
        var parseFeet = parseFloat(this.feet);
        var parseInches = parseFloat(this.inches);
        return parseInt(parseFeet*12+parseInches);
    };

    this.bmi = function() {
        var height = this.inchesConverter();
        var errors = this.validateInput();

        if(errors.length > 0) {
            for(r = 0; r < errors.length; r++){
                return "Please enter a correct number for " + errors[r];
            };

        }

        else {
            return parseFloat((this.weight * 703) / (Math.pow(height, 2))).toFixed(1);
        };
    };  
};

function result(){
    var getWeight = document.getElementById('txtWeight');
    var getFeet = document.getElementById('txtHeightFeet');
    var getInches = document.getElementById('txtHeightInches');

    var test = new calculator(getFeet, getInches, getWeight);
    document.getElementById("lblBMI").innerHTML = test.bmi();
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of assigning `feet.value` to `this.feet` try assigning `feet.getAttribute('value')`

If you console.log(feet) does it show the proper DOM element?

Comment: Why do you expect that to fix the OP's issue? The *value* attribute reflects the value set in the markup (hence *getAttribute*) and has the same value as the *defaultValue* property. The OP wants the current value, which is provided by the *value* property.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to declare the variables with "this."

```
function calculator(paraFeet,paraInches,paraWeight) { 
    var feet = paraFeet.value;
    var inches = paraInches.value;
    var weight = paraWeight.value; 
...
```

you can now remove "this." from every of these variables inside your function

Comment: How about a situation OP wants to get these values from `test` outside of the provided code snippet?

Comment: I think that would be context erasing. I mean the function called "calculator". That's for me: I give some parameters in and get one out. But you're right when a OP wants that, it won't go.

Answer (score 0):

Every browser has JavaScript console on which you can debug your code.
I have some fun to fix it here or there but also you should try it yourself.
Anyway here it is:

```js
function calculator(weight, feet, inches) {
  this.weight = weight;
  this.feet = feet;
  this.inches = inches;

  this.validateInput = function() {
    var errors = [];

    if (!this.validNumber(this.weight, 1000)) {
      errors.push("Invalid weight.");
    }
    if (!this.validNumber(this.feet, 10)) {
      errors.push("Invalid hight in feet.");
    }

    if (!this.validNumber(this.inches, 11)) {
      errors.push("Invalid hight in inches.")
    }
    return errors;
  };

  this.validNumber = function(num, max) {
    if (num.length > 0 && !isNaN(num)) {
      var number = parseInt(num);
      return number > 0 && number < max + 1;
    }
    return false;
  }

  this.displayErrors = function(errors) {
    var html = "";
    for (error of errors)
      html += error + "<br/>";
    return html;
  };

  this.inchesConverter = function() {
    var feet = parseInt(this.feet);
    var inches = parseInt(this.inches);
    return feet * 12 + inches;
  };

  this.bmi = function() {
    var errors = this.validateInput();
    if (errors.length > 0) {
      return this.displayErrors(errors);
    }
    var height = this.inchesConverter();
    return parseFloat((this.weight * 703) / (Math.pow(height, 2))).toFixed(1);
  };
};

function result() {
  var getWeight = document.getElementById('txtWeight').value;
  var getFeet = document.getElementById('txtHeightFeet').value;
  var getInches = document.getElementById('txtHeightInches').value;
  var test = new calculator(getWeight, getFeet, getInches);
  document.getElementById("lblBMI").innerHTML = test.bmi();
  return false;
}
```

```html
<span>
  <label>Weight</label>
  <input id="txtWeight">
</span>
<span>
  <label>HeightFeet</label>
  <input id="txtHeightFeet">
</span>
<span>
  <label>HeightInches</label>
  <input id="txtHeightInches">
</span> 
<button id='run' onClick="return result();">Calculate</button>
<div id="lblBMI"></div>
```